# E2E testing with protractor on Windows 8.1 64-bit

Tags: testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have set up protractor on my machine by installing protractor globally via npm. Then I have updated my webdriver manager and started it.

Now running `protractor protractor-e2e.conf.js` works as it should when I have

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
},
```

but for

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
```

I get just a popup telling me:

```
An administrator has installed Google Chrome on this system, and it is available for all users. The system-level Google Chrome will replace your user-level installation now.
```

How can I resolve this? Should I reinstall Google Chrome? I really would like to test Chrome rather then Firefox...

Comment: did you install chrome driver? http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uninstalled chrome, deleted both directories in

```
c:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\
```

And it works nicely now.